# How to get rid of this nonsense pop-up appearing in Ubuntu while using Chromium browser?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, google-chrome, chromium, google

I am using Ubuntu in a public location where dozens of users come and visit a site and then go, so for each customer it opens google.com and when they are done, it restarts Chromium by killing it first.

Now, everytime, I get this ugly nonsense pop-up appearing to RESTORE which make no sense in my use case.

How to get rid of this ugly pop-up appears all the time in Ubuntu? Is there any command line or settings to completely kill this RESTORE nonsense?

[image]

Comment: Is this your computer or is it just one you're using?

Comment: YES - my computer (used in public location for pilot case, train station)

Comment: What's the transition between sessions? Ie what happens between one person visiting and the next?

Comment: Each person is new browser instance. So when one person browse and leave the camera motion detects "restart the browser" so that next person is available for "fresh browsing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the desired behaviour. I guess there are plenty of ways of dealing with it more professionally. Simplest solution is to use `kill -15` rather than `kill -9`. The former just politely asks google chrome to stop, so it has time to save the data.

If you are running an internet kiosk, you should clean up the profile after each user, however. Create a profile, and then copy it to a temporary location before you start chrome, start chrome with an option `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/the/tmp/profile`, and clean it up before chrome is started again. For example

```
#!/bin/bash

# google chrome starter

PROFILE.DIR=/usr/local/share/default.profile/
TMP.PROFILE=/tmp/google-profile

rm -rf $TMP.PROFILE
cp -a $PROFILE.DIR $TMP.PROFILE
google-chrome --kiosk --user-data-dir=$TMP.PROFILE
```

Thus, every user will start chrome, every user sees the same immutable profile.

Answer (score 1):

If something happens between users (eg they press something to start or end their session), which it seems to be true, I would strongly suggest refreshing the Chrome profile from a master copy (that you store somewhere uneditable but readable by the current user).

```
sudo cp -r ~/.config/google-chrome{,-fresh}/
sudu chown -R root: ~/.config/google-chrome-fresh/
sudo chmod -R o-w  ~/.config/google-chrome-fresh/
```

And then have a script at `~/bin/google-chrome` (or possibly somewhere higher up for security)

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/
cp -r ~/.config/google-chrome{-fresh,}/
google-chrome "$@"
```

And that'll need chmodding +x

The benefit of trashing the runtime profile is people do stupid things when they're using computers. You don't want their installed pluggins interacting with following users. Consider the threat of keyloggers and the like.

Come to think of it, you should probably be using a fresh guest account each time a user comes and dumping the whole user each change. You'd need to shortcut lightdm out of the equation but you could do something manually quite easily with `nodm` and then you get the added benefit of not needing to load an entire desktop just to Kiosk a computer.